# My wifi network doesn't show up 18.10

Tags: networking, 18.10

so the problem is that my wireless network doesn't show up at all. I don't know what could be the problem cause that wifi works perfectly to all the other devices and also in the partition I've of Windows 10. *It shows up other wifi networks*. Thanks in advance for the help :)

Extra data in case is useful: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BbCqXXH5T/

Comment: I shows that you're connected to `devolo-30d32d24446c`, but there's a problem. You have TWO `devolo-30d32d24446c`, one on chan 6 and one on chan 11. What network are you TRYING to reach? Also, it looks like your symlink for `/etc/resolv.conf` is wrong.

Comment: Oh, that's not the problem those are two PLC I've who appears on the list and works perfectly fine. The one that is the main wifi/router and should appear but it doesn't (MOVISTAR_10C0).
And, how can I fix that problem on my symlink? _it's the first time that I've a problem like that_

Comment: What channel is MOVISTAR_10C0 using? We'll discuss the symlink a little later. It's an easy fix.

Comment: Ok, channel 13.
Note: I've got a problem and I had to turn back to 18.04.1, _the wifi problem persist tho_

Comment: Well, that's your problem. Are you in Europe? Your wireless card doesn't go to channel 13. Set your router to use channel 1 or 6 or 11. What problem caused you to go to 18.04.1?

Comment: Yes I'm in Europe but I don't know about that cause my PLC were at ch13 and I made a scan of the channels around me and were wifi from 1-13. And also the thing that the wifi already worked on the same laptop, _Windows 10 partition_. Anyway I'll try it and I would return to you with the result :). Oh and I changed to the nvidia drivers, reboot and the SO was fucked up. I got a backup but I prefer to stick with the 18.04.1 cause I need to work with it and I don't want surprises at least for a time.

Comment: Ok I asume the channel thing goes along with the drivers of ubuntu (?). Changed to 1st channel and works fine!! Thank you so much for the help! :)

Comment: I'll put together a quick answer for you, and include the symlink fix, ok?

Comment: Everything fine thanks, also, would you recomend me to remove the paste link? Cause I don't really know if contains anything that could be used maliciously. Thanks for all the help and your time, much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your question. I don't know what "paste link" means. And no, the symlink fix only corrects how the system resolves DNS requests. It can always be put back easily, if required.

Comment: I refeer to the link I put in the question, the "paste.ubuntu.com..."

Comment: Oh. It's OK to leave the paste link. Glad everything is working for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

The problem was that the desired wireless network was using channel 13, and their wireless card would only go to channel 12. Switched the router to channel 1, and everything is working now.

I had noticed that the `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink was pointing to the wrong place.

`[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']`

We'll reset it...

In `terminal`...

`sudo rm -i /etc/resolv.conf` # delete old symlink

`sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` # recreate the symlink